# Android Listview not displaying the list content

Tags: android, listview

I want to create a listview activity with the HaspMap class to insert the planet, but the text is not showing. 
here is the code

ListView Class
        package com.thenextgeneration.listviewtest;

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import java.util.HashMap;

    import java.util.List;

    import java.util.Map;


    import android.app.Activity;

    import android.os.Bundle;

    import android.widget.ListView;

    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;


    public class Second extends Activity{


    ListView listview;


    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    initList();

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(this, planetsList, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, new String[] {"planet"}, new 
    int[] {android.R.id.text2});
    listview.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);

    }


    List<Map<String, String>> planetsList = new ArrayList<Map<String, 
    String>>();


    private void initList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Mercury"));
    planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Umaru Musa Yaradua 
    University"));
    planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Jupiter"));
    planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Earth"));
    planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Mars"));
    planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Venus"));
    planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Uranus"));
    planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Saturn"));
    planetsList.add(createPlanet("planet", "Neptune"));


    }


    private HashMap<String, String> createPlanet(String key, String 
    name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HashMap<String, String> planet = new HashMap<String, String>();
    return planet;

    }




    }
```

XML Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res   /android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
         >
        </ListView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

it display the list but with an empty text, I have installed the app in my device vut still it display only nthe list without anything

Comment: Maybe a `listview.notifyDatasetChanged()` is needed after setting the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer, You have named "android.R.id.text2" instead of "android.R.id.text1". 
I would suggest you to code in a sequence. enjoy!

```
ListView listview;
List<Map<String, String>> planetsList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    planetsList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    initList();

    listview = new ListView(this);

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdpt = new SimpleAdapter(this, planetsList,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "planet" },
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
    listview.setAdapter(simpleAdpt);
    setContentView(listview);

}

private void initList() {

    Map<String, String> item;
    item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item.put("planet", "Mercury");
    planetsList.add(item);
    item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item.put("planet", "Jupiter");
    planetsList.add(item);
    item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item.put("planet", "Mars");
    planetsList.add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to:

```
 private HashMap<String, String> createPlanet(String key, String 
        name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HashMap<String, String> planet = new HashMap<String, String>();
        planet.put(key,name);
        return planet;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is miss placed. you have first added planetsList to adapter and then initialize and assign value to planetsList. First initialize it, put values in it and then send to adapter or use notifydatasetchanged with adapter in your code.